# How to force DOM modifications done in success function persist within a jQuery.Ajax() call?

Tags: asp.net, javascript, dom, jquery

I am getting a JSON object from a webMethod by the call below and I set some textBox values based on the returned objects attributes.

Problem is, just for a moment my textBoxes are populated but then immidiately they return back to empty.

Do I make a mistake or I cannot make DOM elements modifications within a success function?

Thanks.

```
   var ajaxCallOptions = {
              type: "POST",
              contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
              url: "/JQuery/Chapter16-AJAX/PersonWebServices.asmx/GetPerson",
              context:  document.body,
              data: JSONObject,
              dataType: "json",
              success: function(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest){
                  var myPerson = data;

                  jQuery("#"+"<%=txtFirstName.ClientID %>").val(myPerson.d.FirstName);
                  jQuery("#"+"<%=txtLastName.ClientID %>").val(myPerson.d.LastName);

              },
              error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
                alert('Error: '+textStatus);
              } };

   jQuery.ajax(ajaxCallOptions);
```

The returned data is:

***Additional Note:***
{"d":{"__type":"BusinessObjects.Person","FirstName":"Burak","Id":"001","LastName":"Ozdogan","Department":"Information Technologies"}}

and this is a function which is bound to click event in the form:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSearch" runat="server" Text="Search" OnClientClick="loadPerson($('.personId'));"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `$.ajax()` is fired via a submit the default behavior is likely happening, and reloading the page.

Use `return false;` or `event.preventDefault()` at the end of your submit handler if that is the case.

```
$('.mySubmitButton').submit(function() {
    // Send ajax request
    return false;
});
```

or:

```
$('.mySubmitButton').submit(function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault()
    // Send ajax request
});
```

This same technique is used for links created from `<a href=''>` elements when you want to prevent the default behavior, or for any other element that has a default behavior for that matter.

Comment: It is bound to a click event of a button actually.

Comment: @burak - Is the `<button>` in a `<form>`?

Comment: Thannk you Patrick. With your suggestion I have fixed it. See my own answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest use of [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/) or similar to examine the content being returned by the AJAX call. Failing this, try alerting the data which is returned.

Is the data returned the expected data?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Patrick.

It worked after this modification:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSearch" runat="server" Text="Search" 
OnClientClick="loadPerson($('.personId'), event); return false;"/>
```